# How to check on Friends presence in React Native Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, user-presence

I'm working on an app where I need to show the **friend's presence** *( not all users )*, as you can see in the picture below. I read the docs of Firebase, they mentioned about users presence but they don't mention any thing about this scenario. If I use all users presence method then what will I do if the users are more than 1000? it gets the data downloaded on every change which I don't want.

[image]

There is an idea if I **add multiple listeners for every friend** then it will be efficient or not, if not then what will be the best practice for it.

Thanks